# Linking a link from ERB to the control file

Tags: ruby, erb

I'm trying to make a sort part to my ruby erb list, so far it makes the list then i want a way to sort the list when the click "sort by date". I have no idea where to start?
I'm sure whether to use the href tag or what to use.

```
<table class="user_display">
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Friends</th>
            </tr>
            <% @mentions.each do |name| %>
                <tr>
                  <td><%=h name %></td>
                  <td><%=h date %></td>
                  <td><%=h friends %></td>
                </tr>
            <% end %>
          </table>
```

this isn't the real code but it follows the same ideas with some names changed.
so How do I have a button or link that when they click it reorders the array?
i feel like i should pass something along the lines of

```
<input class="order" type="button" name="date" value="<%=h params[:orderdate] %>"/>
```

is this the right idea, if so how do I link to controller file? which has

```
get '/list' do  
  @mentions = array_of_names
  erb :list
end
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this to the view:

```
<%= link_to 'Order by date', sort_mentions_path(:order_type => 'date'), :class => 'btn' %>
<%= link_to 'Order by name', sort_mentions_path(:order_type => 'name'), :class => 'btn' %>
```

In the controller could be something like this:

```
def sort
  if( params[:order_type] == 'name')
    @mentions = Mention.order('name')
  elsif ( params[:order_type] == 'date')
    @mentions = Mention.order('date')
  else
    @mentions = Mention.all
  end    
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { }
    format.json { render json: @mentions }
  end
end (Remember to add sort.html.erb with the list view)
```

And the route:

```
resources :mentions do
  collection do
    get 'sort'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This will put in @mentions the array ordered by date if you have the Object 'Mention':

`@mentions = Mention.order(:date)`

You don't need to pass any parameter from the view, you can manage the order in the controller

Comment: will that work because i want the user to be able to change the order, so either by date or name or whatever

Comment: I understand, maybe you need to use link_to tag with a :order_type parameter(something like this): <%= link_to 'Order',
              order_mentions_path(:order_type => 'date'), :class => 'btn'  %>